# Closing the off-topic and duplicate questions with bounty

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope, close-reasons, derivatives

There are some questions which has bounty, but are clearly off-topic or are duplicates of another question.

e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/411887/unicode-fonts-are-not-displayed-correctly-in-google-chrome-under-ubuntu-12-04

The above question is offtopic because even though its title say Ubuntu 12.04, its actually about an ubuntu derivetive ElementryOS Luna.

Why can't this be flagged as off-topic even when there is a bounty on it?

I had seen other questions with bounty which were duplicates of nicely answered question. But I dont have an example with me.

Comment: Absolutely agree, I couldn't vote on [this dupe](http://askubuntu.com/q/473005/62483). Sad :(

Comment: No mod reply on the question. Its been 7 months !!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this should be a [feature-request](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/feature-request). My best guess is that the question is locked open once a bounty has been offered and removed from the offerers rep. In a perfect world this would be fine. I added the feature-request tag to the question in the hope that this might be addressed in some fashion. (Even if the response is `Not Going To Happen`)

Edit: Thanks to the comment by Mark Kirby I located [this SE Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/how-can-i-close-a-question-that-has-an-active-bounty) that explains clearly what to do in this situation.

Comment: Thomas told me here http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16170/why-cant-i-vtc-a-question-with-a-bounty on a related question, just flag them, use custom reason and explain :)